# magento backorder per website

Tags: magento, inventory

We need to change backorders per website
Say Product X with quantity 0 can be purchased into WebsiteA but not WebsiteB
Magento allow this attribute to be changed only globally.

My idea was to create another attribute and modify getBackorders function into
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php to watch this new
attribute instead of "backorders"

This modification only affects my product into admin when saving

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with your idea. Create a new attribute that is set on a per website / store view level and then extend the stock item function to look at this value instead.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the best viable solution I've found:

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/allow-backorders-website-scope/

Seems silly that Magento does not have reduced scope for this with the Multi-Source Inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Configure backorders for a products

Product level configurations override global configurations. You may want to configure backorders at the product level to override the settings at the global store or source level. For example, your store may globally support backorders. With product settings, you can disable backorders or change the Out-of-Stock threshold without affecting other products and sources.

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Catalog > Products.
2. Open a product in Edit mode and scroll down the page to the Sources area.
3. For products configured without Inventory Management, the tab does not appear. The Advanced Inventory button is displayed under the Quantity field.
4. Click Advanced Inventory.
5. This action displays a page of product-specific configurations. Any setting listed as global displays the current global setting for the store.
6. For Backorders, deselect the Use Config Setting checkbox and select an option:

Option  Description

No Backorders   To not accept backorders when product is out of stock.
Allow Qty Below 0   To accept backorders when the quantity falls below zero.
Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer   To accept backorders when the quantity falls below zero and to notify the customer that the order can still be placed.